# C++ - accepting command line arguments?

Tags: c++

So this was my original code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float x;  
    cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
    cin >> x;

    if ((x >= 100) && (x < 200)) {
        cout << "split";
    } else if (x == 0 ||x == 1 ) {
        cout << "steal";
    } else {
        cout << "split";
    } 

    system("pause");
}
```

---

It works perfectly, but I need it to run this way:

```
C:\> program.exe 109
```

it will read `109` and give the output - `"steal"`.

```
C:\> program.exe 0.5
```

it will read `0.5` and give me the output `"split"`.

What do I have to add to my original code to do this?

Comment: Hint: see the `>=` and `<=` conditional operators.

Comment: See: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/26251/

Comment: See [main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function).

Answer (score 5):

Change your main to

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
```

The you can check number of specified parameters to your program in `argc` and the values (as `char *`) in `argv`. You can convert that values to float using `std::stof`

```
float x = 0.0f;
if (argc > 1) {
    x = std::stof(argv[1]);
} else {
    std::cerr << "Not enough arguments\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Please note that the first argument to the program is the name of the executable itself (`program.exe` in your case), so you need to check for at least two arguments.

References: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! This is my first time programming, so I really appreciate this!

What is the difference between char** and char*?

And how would I add this to my original code? Do I just add this at the top?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using command line arguments. Here is format for main function:

```
int main (int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
}
```

Here `argc` represents number of arguments(returns 2 in your case, program.exe 0.5 )

`argv` represents two strings. 1st containing `program.exe` and second containing `0.5`.

This way you can solve you problem

Comment: So, will it be:

`#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  float x;  

  if ((x >= 100) && (x < 200)) 

  {cout << "split";}

  else if (x == 0 ||x == 1 )

  {cout << "steal";}

   else

  {cout << "split";} 

  system("pause");

}`

Comment: Please use standard C++ when answering a non-platform specific question: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have more clarity on the question? Do you want to know how to execute the code using command line arguments? In that case here it is:

```
int main (int no_of_args, char* arglist[])
{
}
```

In `argList`, the first item holds the name of the executable and subsequent items hold the inputs provided.

Comment: Hello Priyanka,

I want to know what to add to my original code so that when I run:

C:\> program.exe 109

It reads 109 as an input for x.